# Storing value from SELECT to a variable

Tags: android, mysql

I was making an Android applicaton, which has table called maintable in database.

At first when the user installs my app it will create a row in the table for user which has _id as primary key. And I user query similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) 
VALUES ('val1', 'val2'...);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

By this I get the primary key for sure, but I want to store this value of users primary key into a variable in my application so that I can refer to users information using that value in the variable.

Any help offered will be appreciated. Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the last inserted id, you could do something like:

```
public int getLastInsertedId(){

        String query = "SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int lastInsertedId = 0;
        while(c.moveToNext()){

            lastInsertedId = c.getInt(0);

        }
        c.close();

       return lastInsertedId;

    }
```

You can then save that into a variable such as:

```
int myId = getLastInsertedId();
```

If you want to save that ID for later use, you can save it inside SharedPreferences

```
public void saveId(int id){
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_ID", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("SAVED_ID", id);
    editor.commit();
}

public int getSavedId(){

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SP_ID", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getInt("SAVED_ID", 0);

}
```

Then you can retrieve it like:

```
int storedId = getSavedId();
```

Comment: can tell me what is this "SP_ID" and "SAVED_ID"..?? is it the part of the syntax..?

Comment: SharedPreferences work as a key=>value pair, meaning that to save something to the SP you need to specify a key that will be use to retrieve that particular item, in this case SAVED_ID. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: You need to specify your own keys, but I normally put them in a final static variable because they are used often, in our case we use SAVED_ID twice. They are not part of the syntax.

Comment: but what i need is not this i actually need the code to save the value of id created from database to some variable please send me that.. thanks ie  SELECT    LAST_INSERT_ID();   by that i get the id created but how to store this value to some variable @Azael